# Waiting for images to load in underscore template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm loading images inside underscore. I have a class in my container which has a loader image and it will disappear once my images are loaded.

```
<div id="main_container" class="loading">
<% for (i = 0; i <= pages; i++) { %>
      <img src="/image_<%=i%>.jpg" id="image_<%=i%>" />
      <%
          $('#image_'+i).load(function() {
              $('#main_container').removeClass('loading');
          }).each(function() {
            if(this.complete) $(this).load();
          });
      %>
<% } %>
</div>
```

I can't make it work maybe because the dom is not yet created. Is there a way for me to load the images in underscore template and remove the class loading when the images is completely loaded?

Thanks and more power

Comment: you can use onLoad: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: thanks can you provide an example where I can pass a backbone function inside underscore template?. So I can use that function onLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just render your template with the class `loading` on your `image` and add the callback `onload`

```
<% for (i = 0; i <= pages; i++) { %>
    <img src="/image_<%=i%>.jpg" class='loading' onload='hideLoading(this)' />
<% } %>
```

In your scripts file, add the **callback**

```
function hideLoading(img) {
    $(img).removeClass('loading');
}
```

Comment: What if my function is an underscore view helper?. I can't use this. Say onload='<%hideloading(this)%>' . would not work.

Comment: In that case you can pass a string argument to the function, i.e. the id:
`<img id="img<%=i%>" src="/image_<%=i%>.jpg" class="loading" onload='hideLoading("img<%=i%>")' />` and in the `hideLoading` function you get the element by that id.